# Can a Short Stay Schengen Visa be issued when the passport expires in less than 3 months?

Tags: schengen-visas, greece

I'm an Indian passport holder resident in Ireland. My Irish residency expires in 2023.

I booked a trip to Greece without fully checking the passport requirements.

The intended date of departure from Greece is the 25th of October, 2021, however my passport expires on the 12th of January, 2022.

Which means it violates the minimum requirement of the 3 month passport validity rule.

I'm hoping that since it's only 2 weeks short of the 3 month span, I will be granted the visa.

Are the embassies known to be lenient on the passport requirement based on the fact that I have a USA B1/B2 visa that expires in 2029 and I've visited Greece twice in the past?

Comment: If the passport validity period is a minimum requirement it’s hard to see how or why any discretion would be likely/allowed under the rules.

Comment: @Traveller The rule do in fact allow some discretion (“However, in a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;”) but I don't see how that would apply in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Even if the embassy for whatever reason should ignore the regulations and issue you a visa, the requirement is also checked when you enter Greece. When you fly to Greece, you must expect the airline to verify that your papers are valid for entering Greece and since they are not, deny boarding. And at last, even if also the airline makes a mistake and allows you onboard the plane, immigration control will also verify this and if they don't do a mistake as well, refuse entry.

So your plan is only going to work if both the embassy, the airline and the immigration officer don't see or ignore that your passport expires early. That is not likely to happen.

Comment: (+1) Importantly, it is both a requirement to enter, under article 6(1)(a)(i) of the Schengen Borders Code, *and* a requirement to issue a visa, under article 12(a) of the Visa Code so the mere fact that the OP hasn't provided either a travel document valid for 3 months after the end of the intended stay or a justification why this might be a case of emergency is enough to refuse the visa. I don't doubt some countries are doing it anyway but the Visa Code doesn't seem to provide for the issuance of visas going beyond the validity of the travel document presented, even for multiple-entry visas.

Comment: @Relaxed It is common practice and I can't find anything in the visa code prohibiting the issuance of multiple entry visas beyond the validity of the current passort. The conditions under which multiple entry visa should be issued and the guidelines for determining the duration of a new multiple entry visum (these are further elaborated in the Visa Code Handbook) do also not mention the remaining validity of the current passport as a relevant criteria for deciding how long a new visum should be valid.

Comment: What about article 12? And article 24, especially “unless the validity of the visa would exceed that of the travel document“? This article also explicitly references the article 6(1)(a) of the Schengen Borders Code, thus making its contents directly relevant to visa issuance decisions.

Comment: @Relaxed Article 12 only requires that the is passport is valid three months beyond the last intended departure. If multiple entry visas are issued to travellers with a 'good' visa history for several years, the visa are anyway themselves valid well beyond the *currently* last intended departure. But you are right that the visa handbook (I should sometimes read more thoroughly before saying something) says that also these visa should not be issued beyond the validity of the passport.

Comment: In reality many countries do though and Germany even offers the service to move still valid visas from expired into new passports if the bearer wishes so. German authorities do however also emphasize in their FAQs that a valid visum in an expired passport is valid for travel together with a new passport. I have removed that statement from my answer. It is in any case not relevant for OP's situation.

Comment: That's true but article 12 does seem to preclude issuing a visa in the knowledge that it would be used after the expiration of the travel document presented. Note that there is also case law from the EUCJ prescribing that a valid visa in an invalid passport is enough to satisfy the obligation in article 6 of the Borders Code, provided it is presented together with a valid travel document. At the same time, a travel document can also be invalidated before it expires. In any case, it's certainly a small detail and I had already upvoted your answer.